# How do I make a catch-all URL route in Flask that ignores static files?

Tags: python, flask

How do I make a catch-all url route with Flask that ignores static files like `favicon.ico` and `image.png`?

Examples:

- I want to catch `/bZdFFek` and ignore `/favicon.ico`.
- I want to catch `/of9WfXz` and ignore `/style.css`.

Answer (score 3):

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/design/#the-routing-system) / [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map) will generally do the right thing.  Routes are sorted in order of complexity, so the least complex routes (like "/favicon.ico") should *always* match before catch-all routes:

```
@app.route("/<short_id>")
def view_data(short_id):
    return "You are viewing short ID: {}".format(short_id)

@app.route("/favicon.ico")
def favicon():
    return send_static_file(FAVICON_PATH)
```

Comment: Does this mean I'd been to make a separate route for each file that is automatically loaded with the page, such as `favicon.ico` and `static/css/style.css`?

Comment: @JamesBrewer - Flask adds a `static` route, so routes like `/static/<path:some_file>` will never be matched by `/<some_param>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go would be to use regex in your routing parameters. This answer to another question has a great example of how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5872904/64266