# Why there is no option to add custom url converters to blueprints like for main app?

Tags: python, werkzeug, flask

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870188/does-flask-support-regular-expressions-in-its-url-routing) and in [official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.url_map) we saw how to add custom url converters for main app object.
Here is short example:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['list'] = ListConverter
```

But how to do it for blueprints? This global (app level) custom converter is unavailable for blueprints.
In source code I haven't found such posibility...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical reason why you can't have custom URL converters on a blueprint is that unlike applications, blueprints do not have a URL map.

When you use the blueprint's `route` decorator or `add_url_map()` method all the blueprint does is record the intention to call the application versions of these methods later when `register_blueprint()` is called.

I'm not sure there is a benefit in allowing blueprint specific url converters. But I think it would be reasonable to allow a blueprint to install an app wide converter. That could use the same techniques as other blueprint app-wide handlers, like `before_app_request`, for example.

```
def add_app_url_converter(self, name, f):
    self.record_once(lambda s: s.app.url_map.converters[name] = f
    return f

Blueprint.add_app_url_converter = add_app_url_converter

# ...

bp = Blueprint('mybp', __name__)
bp.add_app_url_converter('list', ListConverter)
```

Comment: O, it's possible to add all blueprints wide converters! All we need is to register such converter for app and only after that to register all blueprints (not vice versa as I did)