# how to preserve leading zeros in Flask routing

Tags: python, regex, flask, jinja2

I'm building URLs that look like this, routing with Flask:

http://hostname/nris/resource/00001234
http://hostname/nris/resource/99000025

The last segment is an 8 digit integer that will match a string in my database. The leading zeros, if any, are significant.

I've implemented a custom regex converter, based on [Does Flask support regular expressions in its URL routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870188/does-flask-support-regular-expressions-in-its-url-routing). That works fine as long as the numeric field starts with a non-zero. Here's my routing code (loaded within `/nris/`):

```
@app.route('/numish/<regex("[0-9]{8}"):resourcenum>/')
def numish(resourcenum):
    return "resourcenum: %s" % (resourcenum)
@app.route('/resource/<regex("[0-9]{8}"):resourcenum>/')
def resource_page(resourcenum):
    return render_template('singlemap.html', propnris=resourcenum)
```

When I visit http://hostname/nris/numish/00000004, I see

```
resourcenum: 00000004
```

But when I display it in my template, all that's shown on the console is 4, and the database query performed in `addSingleSiteLayer()` gets 4, not 00000004. Here's the Jinja code I'm using to generate JavaScript:

```
{% extends "maptemplate.html" %}
{% block mapcustom %}
console.log( "hello" );
console.log( {{propnris}} );
addSingleSiteLayer(map, {{propnris}} );
{% endblock %}
```

I could simply reformat the incoming value into an 8 character string with leading zeros. But I'd rather pass the parameter down so that it doesn't get truncated in the first place. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing your values to *JavaScript*, and it is ignoring the leading zeros on the integer literal you gave it. This is hardly Python or Flask's fault.

Make it a string literal by wrapping the value in quotes:

```html
{% extends "maptemplate.html" %}
{% block mapcustom %}
console.log( "hello" );
console.log( "{{propnris}}" );
addSingleSiteLayer(map, "{{propnris}}" );
{% endblock %}
```

or better still, [format it as JSON](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-filters) to have any quoting issues handled for you:

```html
{% extends "maptemplate.html" %}
{% block mapcustom %}
console.log( "hello" );
console.log( {{propnris|tojson|safe}} );
addSingleSiteLayer(map, {{propnris|tojson|safe}} );
{% endblock %}
```

as Flask's `tojson` filter produces valid JavaScript-compatible JSON output this can be interpreted directly as JavaScript literals, and a Python string is rendered properly quoted.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, for the original problem of the url route in Flask you can now specify  parameter with a fixed number of digits.

e.g.

```
@app.route('/numish/<int(fixed_digits=8):resourcenum>/')
```

The when you use url_for() in your code, the url will be constructed with the correct number of digits.

Further details on the available routing parameters here: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/routing/