# Loop using app.route on Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create several URLs on my serv thanks to a loop . The issue is that each function I create in a app.route can't have the same name than the others . And I don't know how to create different function names ...
Here is the code :

```
json_tweets = []

for line in open('C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\DashboardProject\last_rated_set.json',"r"):
    json_tweets.append(json.loads(line,"ISO-8859-1"))

cashtag_tab = []  

for tweet in json_tweets:
    if not(tweet['cashtag'] in cashtag_tab) :
        cashtag_tab.append(tweet['cashtag'])        

for i in range(0,(len(cashtag_tab)-1)) :
    var=cashtag_tab[i]
    @app.route("/"+var)
    def company(var) :
        finance=Share(var)
        datas =  finance.get_historical('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31')
        datas = json.dumps(datas, default=json_util.default)    
        return datas
```

I'm getting the error    AssertionError : View function mapping is overwritting an existing endpoint function : company

Answer (score 1):

This fails because Flask derives the endpoint name from the function by default, but it would anyway fail later because the function `company` requires an argument `var` and the route is not parameterised. The simplest option would be just checking the value inside the handler:

```
@api.route('/<var>')
def company(var):
    if var not in cashtag_tab:
        abort(404)
```

If you want all the routes to be in the routing map for any reason, I once needed a similar thing and came up with something like this:

```
def url_family(source, methods=('GET',)):
    def decorator(f):
        for entry in source:
            # create a handler that delegates to your function
            def view_func(entry=entry, **kwargs):
                return f(entry, **kwargs)

            endpoint = '{0}_{1}'.format(f.__name__, entry)
            url = '/{0}'.format(entry)

            api.add_url_rule(url, 
                             methods=methods,
                             endpoint=endpoint,
                             view_func=view_func)

    return decorator
```

Then you register the handlers as:

```
@url_family(cashtag_tab)
def company(var):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using flask now, you should consider Custom URL Converter. Check links below

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.url_map - url_map UrlConverter API
https://exploreflask.com/views.html#url-converters - example url converter
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5872904/3451543 - RegexConverter by [Philip Southam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332911/philip-southam)

Anyway, specifying more details on your question is always helpful to get accurate answer :)

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast, I am new in both stackoverflow and python, I'll give more details next time . I'm going to look into the links you provided me