# Regular expression in flask urls

Tags: python, regex, flask, flask-restful

I want to write some urls in flask using regular expression. I have them in django like this

```
r'^v1/$'
r'^v1/(.+/)$'
```

I want to recreate them in flask

I have tried following

```
class RegexConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, *items):
        super(RegexConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
        self.regex = items[0]
app.url_map.converters['regex'] = RegexConverter

api.add_resource(Handler1,'/<regex("^v1/$")>')
api.add_resource(Handler2,'/<regex("^v1/(.+/)$")>')
```

But it's not working.
Showing error

```
ValueError: malformed url rule: '/<regex("^v1/$")>'
```

Comment: Take a look at this: [Does Flask support regular expressions in its URL routing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870188/does-flask-support-regular-expressions-in-its-url-routing)

Comment: I had taken above code from that example only

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the `url_map` rule value. It should be:

```
class RegexConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, *items):
        super(RegexConverter, self).__init__(url_map)
        self.regex = items[0]
app.url_map.converters['regex'] = RegexConverter

api.add_resource(Handler1,'/<regex("^v1/$"):just_v1>')
api.add_resource(Handler2,'/<regex("^v1/(.+/)$"):v1_plus>')
```

And, in your actual handlers (here `Handler1` and `Handler2`); you'll receive those mapped values as parameters:

```
class Handler1(Resource):
    def get(self, just_v1):
        # you'll receive `v1/` as the value for `just_v1`
```

Comment: Still not working for url : http://localhost:6000/v1//

Comment: @sarvesh Probably add more code with the handlers, api/app objects initialisation etc. in the question?

Comment: It is same code as you have written. One more thing removing `^` from regular expression is working