# Flask app route for paths that start with X

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, path, app-route

I am a beginner with **Flask** and **python**. I want to create a handler function for paths that start with "/favicon". For example the following should be handled:

- /favicon
- /faviconFOO
- /favicon_bar
- /favicon/buzz
- /favicon1337

The following should not be handled:

- /favico
- /favicoN
- /whatever

If Flask supporeted wildcards, it would be "/favicon*"

EDIT: I don't need support for regular expressions.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want all routes: `favicon`, `faviconFOO`, `favicon_bar` etc. to point same handle, then you may look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870188/does-flask-support-regular-expressions-in-its-url-routing)

Comment: Yes exactly. If it was a wildcard it would be /favicon*

Comment: I would not say it's a duplicate because it is much more spesific than the other question. Besides, I don't care if it is solved using regex or not.

Comment: It can be perfectly solved with regex, I guess it would be the best way to reduce redundancy in this case(flask). However Django framework has more convenient support for regexs'.

Comment: please let me know if the answer did what you wanted if you found another way to do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would do a `catch-all` url and then, try to use a `wildcard` with it from inside the view:

```
@app.route('/<path:text>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def all_routes(text):
    if text.startswith('favicon'):
        #do stuff
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('404_error'))
```

you can use `string` too:

```
@app.route('/<string:text>', methods=['GET'])
```

but using `string` wouldn't catch `/` strings. so if string is used, `url's` containing  something like `favicon/buzz` wouldn't be cached by it, `path` in the other hand would catch `/`'s too. so you should go with first option.

you can look at [routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#routing) documentation in flask site. and you `should` create a better conditional than `if x in Y` because it will fail if you were passed something like `/thingfavicon`