# Can you make a dynamic route with / in the middle of the dynamic part in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a program with Flask that let's you quickly create pages. Basically I want to make it so I can have slashes (`/`) in dynamic URLs e.g. the route is `<page>` and I enter `localhost:5000/test/page`, I want it to go to `<page>` with the `<page>` being `test/page`.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Flask documentation on [URL variables](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules):

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!\n'

@app.route('/path/<path:subpath>')
def show_subpath(subpath):
    return 'Subpath %s\n' % subpath
```

Example requests from the command line:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
Hello, World!
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/path/test/page
Subpath test/page
```

If you wanted to do something similar with regular expressions, the common solution seems to be [adding a regex 'converter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870188/does-flask-support-regular-expressions-in-its-url-routing/5872904), but the `path` URL variable appears to exist for exactly what you're asking about.