# Use regular expressions to extract information from a URL

Tags: python, flask

How to get page id by URL in Flask?

```
http://localhost/page34
http://localhost/page35
```

I want the word "page" to be fixed with a letter or number next to it representing the page, how do I do this?

Comment: Why not simply `http://localhost/page/34`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5872904/15239951). You can also use [this example](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/routing/#custom-converters) from the documentation of `Werkzeug`.

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class RegexConverter(BaseConverter):
    def __init__(self, url_map, *items):
        super().__init__(url_map)
        self.regex = items[0]

app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['regex'] = RegexConverter

@app.route('/page<regex("\d+"):page_id>/')
def page(page_id):
    return f"Page ID: {page_id}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that's what I want..
Thanks!